# Create correlation function in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a correlation function in MySql 5 that takes in two columns (x, y) and returns a single Decimal value (correlation_coefficient).

Here is my function definition

```
-- Calculate pearson correlation coefficient.
-- INPUT: X and Y should be columns of data (decimal) 
-- RETURN: A value between -1 and 1 depending on the strength of the relationship between the 2 columns e.g. 0.43.

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION PearsonCorrelation(
    x Decimal(10,1),
    y Decimal(10,1)
)
RETURNS Decimal(10,1)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE correlation_coefficient  DECIMAL(3,2);
    SET correlation_coefficient = (avg(x * y) - avg(x) * avg(y)) / (sqrt(avg(x * x) - avg(x) * avg(x)) * sqrt(avg(y * y) - avg(y) * avg(y)));
    RETURN(correlation_coefficient);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I execute the function call, I get the error 'invalid use of group function'. Here are some test data, where the correlation coefficient returned from the dataset should be
0.86.

```
CREATE TABLE data_table
(
x Decimal(3,1) NOT NULL,
y Decimal(3,1) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO data_table 
VALUES(11.2, 10.4),
(9.7, 4.6),
(4.5, 2.1)
```

I would intend to call this function as follows:

```
Select PearsonCorrelation(x,y) as corrcoef
FROM data_table
```

Given feedback, my question may be reframed to say, is it possible to pass in table columns as arguments in to the correlation function and if so, how do I adapt the function to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify by providing sample data and expected outcome, as is function makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe this could be relevant for your needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014741/macro-concept-in-sql

Comment: Test data added.

Comment: - You cannot pass table data to a function and a function is self contained knowing nothing about the table in the calling statement. and you haven't shown how you invoke the function

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon. I've updated the question given your feedback.

Comment: There seems to be no reason whatever to have a function...or the question is oversimplified.Perhaps your desire is carry out a correlation calculation on many different tables all with x,y columns?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass columns of table data to a MySQL stored function. You Can't Do That™. [Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) like AVG() only work in the context of SQL statements like SELECT -- statements that mention FROM sometable.

You could try something like this.

```sql
 SELECT (AVG(x * y) - AVG(x) * AVG(y)) /
        (SQRT(AVG(x * x) - AVG(x) * AVG(x)) *
         SQRT(AVG(y * y) - AVG(y) * AVG(y))) correlation_coefficient
  FROM data_table;
```

You should know that MySQL translates all numbers to double-precision floating point before doing arithmetic on them. `DECIMAL(3,1)` is probably not a good choice of data format.

Some other makes and versions of table server let you create your own [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html), but not MariaDB / MySQL.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I know I can write it out as per your answer, I just need to use the function ALOT so I was trying to avoid that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` Function has no meaning here..
only in a select statement like this, where it will give you the average of values.

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products);
```

just remove all AVG() from the code

Comment: Thanks. But then I still need to compute the average?

Comment: average of one number is just the number.  no need to use the average here at all..

Comment: I believe I do, because I am trying to calculate the correlation between two columns. This isn't a row by row calculation. I need to understand the populations statistics as part of the equation to calculate the correlation.

Comment: this function has 2 decimal parameters.. not two table columns. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764039/4343230